# Get element using class name

Tags: html, dom

I am trying to get a `div` element with the class `result` from my html file, and then add another div inside it using 2 functions like so:

```js
function makeDiv() {
  const parentDiv = document.createElement("div");
  parentDiv.setAttribute("id", "myDiv");
  parentDiv.setAttribute("class", "container");

  const p1 = document.createElement("p");
  p1.textContent = "Hello Everyone";
  parentDiv.appendChild(p1);

  return parentDiv;
}

function addDiv() {
  const div1 = makeDiv();
  div2 = document.querySelector(".result");
  div2.appendChild(div1);
}
```

In my html file, I have a `div` element inside my main like so:

```html
<div id="q2">
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried using both `querySelector` and `getElementsByClassName` but the line

```js
div2 = document.querySelector(".result");
```

is still returning null. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct didn't you forgot to call your `addDiv` function?

```js
function makeDiv() {
  const parentDiv = document.createElement("div");
  parentDiv.setAttribute("id", "myDiv");
  parentDiv.setAttribute("class", "container");

  const p1 = document.createElement("p");
  p1.textContent = "Hello Everyone";
  parentDiv.appendChild(p1);

  return parentDiv;
}

function addDiv() {
  const div1 = makeDiv();
  div2 = document.querySelector(".result");
  div2.appendChild(div1);
}

addDiv()
```

```html
<div id="q2">
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it is saying "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" in the line "div2 = document.querySelector(".result");"

Comment: Can you reproduce it in code snipper or sandbox? As you can see runing code snippet above – it works.

Comment: Strange, I have the same code, but it is still saying the same error...

Comment: Do you have your js and html code in the same page?

Comment: It is on 2 separate files, but I have properly linked them together already.

Comment: then put your `<script>` tag after `<div id="q2">` in html

Comment: I have included it in my <head> tag already, shouldn't that apply to the whole file ?

Comment: yes but when you run function inside your js file the html tree is not ready yet, so put your tag `<script>` before closing `</body>` to be sure that all the html above parsed by browser and available for js

Comment: Okay I have tried that but still no result.

Comment: a bit misunderstand here i wanted to say put your `<script>` tag after `<div class="result"></div>` in html